# Change of Variable Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the region in the first quadrant bounded by the parabolas $y=x^2, y=2x^2, x=y^2,$ and $x=2y^2$. Use change of coordinates to find the area of the region.

I've set $u=x$ and $v=y$ so the equations would be $v=u^2, v=2u^2, u=v^2,$ and $u=2v^2$, but I don't know where to go from here

Comment: If you set $u=x$ and $v=y$, you don't really perform a change of coordinates, you only replace one symbol $x$ ($y$) with another $u$ ($v$).

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you would be asked to solve a problem like this if there had been no examples of "using change of coordinates to find the area" in your textbook or course notes. A good starting point would be to compare one of those problems to this one. Perhaps the earlier example was not adequately explained to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea how the graphs look like then you have to calculate all  intersection points of two functions.

Case 1: $y=x^2, y=2x^2$

Here there is no substitution needed.

$2x^2=x^2$

$2x^2-x^2=0$

$x^2=0 \Rightarrow x_1=0 $

The intersection point is $P_1(0/0)$

Case 2: $y=x^2, x=y^2$

$x=y^2\Rightarrow y=\sqrt x$

$x^2=\sqrt x$

Let $u=\sqrt x$. Then $x^2=u^4$

$u^4=u$

$u^4-u=0$

$u(u^3-1)=0$

A product of two factors is zero if at least on factor is zero.

$u_2=0\Rightarrow x_2=0\Rightarrow P_2(0/0)$

$u^3-1=0$

$u^3=1$

$u_3=1 \Rightarrow x_3=1 \Rightarrow y_3=1\Rightarrow P_3(1/1)$

Up to here (two cases) the bounded area is between the functions $y=x^2$ and  $y=\sqrt x$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$

You have to find the other intersection points. There are 4 additional cases. $P(0/0)$ is the lowest intersection point in the first quadrant. You have to find another intersection point where $x,y>0$ and where the values of $x$ and $y$ are smaller or equal than of all other intersection points.